# AuthGuard not showing component

Tags: angular

I realise this is very vague but I don't know what's happening. I am trying to use AuthGuard to protect components until someone is logged in. These components show up when not using AuthGuard but as soon as I use AuthGuard the children components there is nothing loading and no errors in the console.

I have tried following the other issues like this stackoverflow recommended but they're not having similar problems and it hasn't worked.

app-routing:

```
{
  path:"",
  component: ProjectHomeComponent,
  canActivate : [ AuthGuard ],
  children: [
    {
      path: "",
      children: [
        { path: 'view', component: ProjectViewComponent },
        { path: 'seeManage', component: ProjectManageComponent }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
```

auth.guard:

```
checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
  if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) { return true; }

  this.authService.redirectUrl = url;

  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  return false;
}
```

full auth.guard:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
      let url: string = state.url;

      return this.checkLogin(url);
    }

  checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
    if(document.getElementById('username').innerHTML==""){
      this.authService.redirectUrl = url;

      this.router.navigate(['/login']);

      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

//got a lot of this from the angular docs so some bits might be unneccessary
```

I expect the components to load when I use AuthGuard and logged in, the same way they do without AuthGuard. Nothing is loading and there are no errors in the console.

Comment: Could you please provide the complete code of your `auth.guard.ts`

Comment: First thing I would do is add `enableTracing : true` to your router. It will help you when debugging resolver/guard issues. Second thing, if you want to guard child routes as well, you need to use `canActivateChild` and also implement the corresponding method in your AuthGuard.

Comment: added full auth guard

Comment: `RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component:ProjectHomeComponent },
      { path: 'view', component:ProjectViewComponent },
      { path: 'manage', component:ProjectManageComponent }
    ])`This is my RouterModule in my imports on app.module, where do I enableTracing?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have forgot to implement the `CanActivateChild` interface in your `auth.guard.ts` (see [here](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateChild)).

Your `auth.guard.ts` should look like this:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivateChild{

    canActivateChild(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) { return true; }
        this.authService.redirectUrl = state.url;
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I tried adding what you said and it was still routing me back to my '' route, I can see the '/view' or '/seeManage' come up in the url and then it just pulls back to ''